# This ITextSharp C# code generates empty pdf ? why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, webforms, itext

I am calling this method from a submit button which is not relevant. The `Bindgv();` function binds database to gridview and then this code generates 
empty PDF, I am not sure why. If anyone can fix this i will be thankfull.

```
 private void ExportToPdf()
 {
    gv.AllowPaging = true;
    Bindgv();

    //Create a table
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(gv.Columns.Count);
    table.SpacingAfter = table.SpacingBefore = 5;

    //Set the column widths
    int[] widths = new int[gv.Columns.Count];
    for (int x = 0; x < gv.Columns.Count; x++)
    {
        widths[x] = (int)gv.Columns[x].ItemStyle.Width.Value;
        string cellText = Server.HtmlDecode(gv.HeaderRow.Cells[x].Text);
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cellText));
        cell.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(System
                           .Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#008000"));
        table.AddCell(cell);
    }
    table.SetWidths(widths);

    //Transfer rows from GridView to table
    for (int i = 0; i < gv.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        //does not enter here
        if (gv.Rows[i].RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < gv.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                string cellText = Server.HtmlDecode
                                  (gv.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text);
                iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell cell = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell(new Phrase(cellText));

                //Set Color of Alternating row
                if (i % 2 != 0)
                {
                    cell.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(System.Drawing
                                        .ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#C2D69B"));
                }
                table.AddCell(cell);
            }
        }
    }

    //Create the PDF Document
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    pdfDoc.Add(table);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;" +
                                   "filename=BillHistory.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();
}
```

Here is the `Bindgv();`

```
private void Bindgv()
{
    var idParam = new SqlParameter
    {
        ParameterName = "accNo",
        Value = txtAccountNo.Text
    };

    List<BillHistory> bh = new List<BillHistory>();
    bh = db.ExecuteStoreQuery<BillHistory>("exec BillHistory @accNo", idParam).ToList();
    gv.DataSource = bh;
    gv.DataBind();


    customer_registration cus = db.customer_registration.SingleOrDefault(p => p.account_number == txtAccountNo.Text);
    lblAccountNo.InnerHtml = cus.account_number;
    lblMeterNo.InnerHtml = cus.meter_number;
    lblPremises.InnerHtml = cus.apartment_number + "," + cus.house_name + "," + cus.street_name;
    lblBillingAddress.InnerHtml = cus.apartment_number + "," + cus.house_name + "," + cus.street_name;
    lblOwner.InnerHtml = cus.customer_name;
}
```

Comment: In debug mode, check what is the result of gv.Rows.Count after the call to BindGv method

Comment: its 23. i also taught this code be the problem but it was not.

Comment: I just tried your code by replacing pdfDoc.Add(table) with pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World")) and it works. Can you try that. If it does, it must be a problem with the grid view loading data into your pdfTable

Comment: You send the PDF directly to the response output stream. While that surely is good for your resources, this also means that no content length header can be sent. Some browsers require that header.

Comment: @PraveenPaulose yes it works for me too. i am updating the question to give the Bindgv(); method contents too. i recieve this error when opening the original file from Adobe pdf reader
_An error exits in this page acrobat may not display the page corectly_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll need to handle the GridView's [`DataBound`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event and create the PDF as part of that event.